# Add filename and creation date to SQL Server table along with the values held in a text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

[image]I have package created in SSIS where it loops over a directory with over 50 text files. The text files are comma delimited (sorry I can't show an example the details as its data protection)

I have successfully managed to use SSIS for each loop to enter the values into the SQL Server table. What I need to enter along side is the filename and creation date into the SQL Server table for every row that exist in the text file.

Just wondering how this would be possible? Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: use a derived column?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have set up a `For Each File` loop container, ensure you have [set up a variable to capture the filename](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx).  You can then use this variable in a `Derived Column` transformation after your `Excel Source` to add the column to the dataflow from the variable in your Data Flow.

If you have not included the created date in your filename which you can parse out in SSIS, you will need to look at [creating your own script task](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/anandctutorials/article.php/c5861/Working-with-Files-in-C.htm) or [using custom transformations](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=File%20Properties%20Task&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: Thank you Dave, Yes i have got a for each loop container going through each text file as source, would the derived column go next before the OLE DB destination?

Comment: @abs786123 It would need to go at any point after your Source and before your Destination.  If you have other transformations doing things to your data, you may want to put it before or after those depending on what your package is doing.

Comment: I maybe doing something wrong here, but I think its the variable bit, how do I go about getting the name of the file into the variable? I am using the variable in the derived table which is used for mapping bit on the for each? Am i doing this wrong

Comment: Sorry Dave scrap that just noticed you send a link, i shall have a look

Comment: Hi Dave, I have tried as per tutorial but it seems to be giving this error message above. I have change the error count from the default to 1000 but still can't run. Any ideas as to what it could be?

Comment: @abs786123  What is the error message given in the Output window and what have you used as the expression to create the value for your derived column?

Comment: I have used the same variable used for the 'For Each' Loop Mapping which would use the filename? The error message is showing maximum count of errors which i cant make any sense over, unless there are detailed version of this error i can get from somewhere in BIDS somewhere? But i put the maximum error count to 1000 but still no success

Comment: @abs786123  You need to read the entire Output to find the correct error message.  It will be prefixed with `ERROR:` though there will be several.  You have simply read the one nearest the bottom of the Output window.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a piece on [What is the name of the file](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/05/ssis-what-is-name-of-file.html)

For Flat File Source, you can pull the file name in directly via the Advanced properties by setting the `FileNameColumnName` property.

A re-usable approach would be to add a Derived Column to the data flow and add the Variable name that is being populated in the Variable Mapping tab of your Foreach (file) Enumerator. I have assumed it's `CurrentFileName` and thus my derived column would look like

- CurrentFileName
- DT_STR 1252
- 130
- `@[User::CurrentFileName]`